# How to handle synchronization of frequent concurrent read/writes on a Java ArrayList

Tags: java, concurrency, arraylist

I have a Java class that contains an `ArrayList` of transaction info objects that get queried and modified by different threads on a frequent basis. At a basic level, the structure of the class looks something like this (currently no synchronization is present):

```
class Statistics
{
    private List<TranInfo> tranInfoList = new ArrayList<TranInfo>();

    // This method runs frequently - every time a transaction comes in.
    void add(TranInfo tranInfo)
    {
        tranInfoList.add(tranInfo);
    }

    // This method acts like a cleaner and runs occasionally.       
    void removeBasedOnSomeCondition()
    {
        // Some code to determine which items to remove

        tranInfoList.removeAll(listOfUnwantedTranInfos);
    }

    // Methods to query stats on the tran info.
    // These methods are called frequently.
    Stats getStatsBasedOnSomeCondition()
    {
        // Iterate over the list of tran info
        // objects and return some stats
    }


    Stats getStatsBasedOnSomeOtherCondition()
    {
        // Iterate over the list of tran info
        // objects and return some stats
    }
}
```

I need to ensure that read/write operations on the list are synchronized correctly, however, performance is very important, so I don't want to end up locking in every method call (especially for concurrent read operations). I've looked at the following solutions:

### CopyOnWriteArrayList

I've looked at the use of a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) to prevent ConcurrentModificationExceptions being thrown when the list is modified while iterating over it; the problem here is the copy required each time the list is modified... it seems too expensive given how often the list will be modified and the potential size of the list.

### ReadWriteLock

A [ReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) could be used to synchronize read/write operations while allowing concurrent read operations to take place. While this approach will work, it ends up resulting in a lot of synchronization code in the class (this isn't the end of the world though).

---

Are there any other clever ways of achieving this kind of synchronization without a big performance penalty, or are one of the above methods the recommended way? Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How frequently is the list modified? How big is it?

Comment: ReadWriteLock is the correct solution IMO.  If the mixing of concerns bothers you, insert a level of proxying.

Comment: Do you know this is problem because I wouldn't assume you are calling these methods often enough to cause a problem. i.e. is it 1K/s, 10K/s, 100K/s or 1M/s?

Comment: If you don't want locking in every method call, and you don't want to copy the whole list on each write, you'll need to abandon random ordered access for a `List`.  Maybe a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`?

Comment: It seems that you have exceeded the design intent for ArrayList.  Perhaps you should consider another, more specialized, container.  This sounds like a job for a concurrent queue or synchronizedList.  Have you looked at those?

Comment: The volumes for current clients aren't huge, but they will be considerably bigger for future clients. These comments alone have helped me realise that I'm over-thinking this and possibly fallen into the "premature optimization" trap. I'm going to go with @Marcel Stör's solution... get something working now and performance test/optimize later on. Thanks to everyone for the advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `Collections.synchronizedList()` until you *know for sure* that it is indeed the crucial performance bottle neck of your application (needless to say I doubt it is ;-)). You can only know for sure through thorough testing. I assume you know about "premature optimization"...

If then you strive to optimize access to that list I'd say `ReadWriteLock` is a good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that may make sense (especially under heavy read/write) is ConcurrentLinkedQueue (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html). It is a pretty scalable implementation under contention, based on CAS operations.

The one change that's required to your code is that ConcurrentLinkedQueue does not implement the List interface, and you need to abide by either the Iterable or the Queue type. The only operation you lose really is random access via index, but I don't see that being an issue in your access pattern.